# Retrofit with POST

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my Api interface:

```
public interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/")
    public void feed(@Field("tag") String tag,
                      @Field("id") int id,
                      Callback<String> respone);


}
```

Here is the mothod I called in MainActivity:|

```
public static void setBody(int i) {
    final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(WELCOM_URL).build();
    Api vocApi = restadapter.create(Api.class);
    vocApi.feed("get_about", 11, new Callback<String>() {


        @Override
        public void success(String obj, Response response) {
            Log.d("Great", obj.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Errrorrr..", error.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

if it is correct, it will return a string of JSon Object.
My problem is I got this message:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

So, is there any problem in my code?
Thanks

Comment: where is your url in interface method? I don't think @POST("/")  is correct you need to specify the url that will be appended to your endpoint.

Comment: You're expecting a String in your Callback but you said that you return a JSON object. You should create a POJO with the structure of your response JSON and pass it to the callback instead of String.

Comment: Can you post the JSON response after making the API call?

Answer (score 0):

For a perfect solution i need more details such as your return json from your api but according to your error log retrofit gets json object from api and you are trying to get it as a string.

I modified your code:

```
public static void setBody(int i) {
    final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(WELCOM_URL).build();
    Api vocApi = restadapter.create(Api.class);
    vocApi.feed("get_about", 11, new Callback<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void success(JSONObject obj, Response response) {
            Log.d("Great", obj.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Errrorrr..", error.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

For results of retrofit you have to create POJOS which matches your return json object from your api and give it to Retrofit Callback like

```
new Callaback<YourResponseBean>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

We have to create new POJO for Callback object. We can not use it directly as a string response or any Json object. 
Here the code for Api interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/")
public void feed(@Field("tag") String tag,
                  @Field("id") int id,
                  Callback<Profile> respone);
```

Class Profile:

```
public class Profile {
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    public double latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    public double longitude;
    @SerializedName("error")
    public boolean error;
    ---
    Constructor
    Getter and Setter
    ----

}
```

Called method:

```
public static void setBody(int i) {
    final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(WELCOM_URL).build();
    Api vocApi = restadapter.create(Api.class);
    vocApi.feed("get_about", i, new Callback<Profile>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Profile obj, Response response) {
            Log.d("sadf", obj.isError() +"-"+obj.getLatitude()+ "-" + obj.getLongitude());
        }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.e("1Errrorrr..", error.toString());
    }
});
```

}